# GUI Layout Problems [STILL require help]

Tags: user-interface, layout, jpanel, grid-layout

I can't figure out how to do a layout like the one below:
[image]

Excuse my atrocious writing. My tablet is nowhere to be found so I had to use my mouse. 
Anyway, I'd just like to know how to properly do something like that with my Tic-Tac-Toe game.

I've got the grid where it should be but I can't for the life of me get the title on the screen too. I'd also like to know how to do a simple strip of solid color like shown. I've tried that too but it wouldn't always appear. Sometimes it would while other times it flashes and then disappears or it just doesn't appear at all.

I'd say it probably has something to do with the way I've set my layout but I couldn't figure out how to do the grid otherwise. Oh! I also figured that if I figured out what was wrong with the whole panel-adding-to-frame thing, I could probably figure out why the red error text that's supposed to show when you try to click on an already occupied button doesn't show up either. I'm pretty sure it's the same problem.

Here's my code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Code implements ActionListener {

JFrame frame = new JFrame ("Tic-Tac-Toe");

JLabel title = new JLabel ("Tic-Tac-Toe"); //displayed title of the program
JLabel error = new JLabel (""); //label that says error if you make a move on a
//non-blank button

JPanel titlestrip = new JPanel (); //the strip behind the title
JPanel bgpanel = new JPanel (); //the background panel that fills up the window
JPanel bgpanel2 = new JPanel (); //second bg panel with no layout 
JPanel buttonpanel = new JPanel(); //the panel that holds the nine buttons

JButton one = new JButton ("");
JButton two = new JButton ("");
JButton three = new JButton ("");
JButton four = new JButton ("");
JButton five = new JButton (""); 
JButton six = new JButton ("");
JButton seven = new JButton ("");
JButton eight = new JButton ("");
JButton nine = new JButton ("");

GridBagConstraints x = new GridBagConstraints ();

static String symbol = ""; //stores either an X or an O when the game begins
static int count = 0; //hidden counter; even for one player & odd for the other

public Code() {
    Code();
}

private void Code(){
    titlestrip.setLayout(null);
    titlestrip.setBackground(new Color (0x553EA5)); //color of the strip behind                                        title
    titlestrip.setLocation (98,5);
    titlestrip.setSize (400, 50);

    title.setFont(new Font("Rockwell Extra Bold", Font.PLAIN, 48)); //font settings
    title.setForeground(new Color (0x10CDC6)); //title color

    bgpanel.setBackground(new Color(0x433F3F)); //background color
    bgpanel.setLayout(FlowLayout());

    bgpanel2.setBackground(new Color(0x433F3F)); 

    frame.setVisible (true);
    frame.setSize (500,500);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    buttonpanel.setLayout (new GridLayout(3,3));
    buttonpanel.add(one);
    buttonpanel.add(two);
    buttonpanel.add(three);
    buttonpanel.add(four);
    buttonpanel.add(five);
    buttonpanel.add(six);
    buttonpanel.add(seven);
    buttonpanel.add(eight);
    buttonpanel.add(nine);
    buttonpanel.setSize (200,200);
    buttonpanel.setLocation(150, 150);

    one.addActionListener(this);
    two.addActionListener(this);
    three.addActionListener(this);
    four.addActionListener(this);
    five.addActionListener(this);
    six.addActionListener(this);
    seven.addActionListener(this);
    eight.addActionListener(this);
    nine.addActionListener(this);

    bgpanel.add(buttonpanel);
    bgpanel2.add(title);

    x.gridx = 150;
    x.gridy = 400;
    bgpanel2.add(error, x);

    frame.add(bgpanel2);
    frame.add(bgpanel); 
}
private LayoutManager FlowLayout() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
//- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - [ END ] - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - //
//- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -[ LAYOUT ] - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - //
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new SummativeCode();
}
//- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - //
//- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - //
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    count = count + 1;
    String text = (String)e.getActionCommand(); //stores the kind of text in the button pressed
    //Checks which player is making a move
    if (count %2 == 0){
        symbol = "X";
    }
    else {
        symbol = "O";
    }

    //- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - //
    //- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - //
    //sets the text in the button with an X or an O depending on whose turn it is
    if (e.getSource() == one){
        if (text.equals("")){ //if text is blank, do the following
            one.setText(symbol);
        }
        else { //if it's not blank, display error
            error.setText("This is an occupied button. Please choose again.");
            error.setForeground(Color.red);
        }
    }
    if (e.getSource() == two){
        if (text.equals("")){
            two.setText(symbol);
        }
        else {
            error.setText("This is an occupied button. Please choose again.");
            error.setForeground(Color.red);
        }
    }
    if (e.getSource() == three){
        if (text.equals("")){
            three.setText(symbol);
        }
        else {
            error.setText("This is an occupied button. Please choose again.");
            error.setForeground(Color.red);
        }
    }
    if (e.getSource() == four){
        if (text.equals("")){
            four.setText(symbol);
        }
        else {
            error.setText("This is an occupied button. Please choose again.");
            error.setForeground(Color.red);
        }
    }
    if (e.getSource() == five){
        if (text.equals("")){
            five.setText(symbol);
        }
        else {
            error.setText("This is an occupied button. Please choose again.");
            error.setForeground(Color.red);
        }
    }
    if (e.getSource() == six){
        if (text.equals("")){
            six.setText(symbol);
        }
        else {
            error.setText("This is an occupied button. Please choose again.");
            error.setForeground(Color.red);
        }
    }
    if (e.getSource() == seven){
        if (text.equals("")){
            seven.setText(symbol);
        }
        else {
            error.setText("This is an occupied button. Please choose again.");
            error.setForeground(Color.red);
        }
    }
    if (e.getSource() == eight){
        if (text.equals("")){
            eight.setText(symbol);
        }
        else {
            error.setText("This is an occupied button. Please choose again.");
            error.setForeground(Color.red);
        }
    }
    if (e.getSource() == nine){
        if (text.equals("")){
            nine.setText(symbol);
        }
        else {
            error.setText("This is an occupied button. Please choose again.");
            error.setForeground(Color.red);
        }
    }
}   
}
```

Thanks for any help and excuse my probably terrible coding logic.

Answer (score 0):

With games, it is often best to override paint(Graphics).

Use the following psuedocode inside the method:

```
setColor(backColor);
drawRect(0,0,width,height);
setColor(foreColor);
drawRect(0,0,width,150); // I'm just guessing that your top is 150 pixels
drawImage(bufferedTTT,Op,width/2-bufferedTTT.width/2, 15) // to center the heading, you can use drawText, but it would be a lot harder for the same effect
setColor(black)
drawLine(...)
... // draw Lines for TTT board.
```

[image: Image failed to load.]

Comment: I'd appreciate if you could make the heading image (with panels, right?), just to see how I would do it. And er, so I don't use GridLayout...? I'm a little confused.

Comment: You don't use any layout, I'm saying to programmatically paint directly on the screen. [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#paintComponent(java.awt.Graphics)) And I'll add the image after making it.

Comment: Then would I have to manually arrange the buttons within the drawn grid? I guess that could work though I prefer the GridLayout to be honest. D: Thanks so much for your help though! Do you happen to know how to fix my problem though? Keeping it the way it is but just having the title show through as well?

Comment: Get rid of the buttons, and use a MouseListener.

Comment: Oh gosh, I've tried MouseListener before. It and I don't exactly get along. I just find it so much more difficult to use for some odd reason.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues with the code you posted:

- Swing components should only be accessed from the Event Dispatch Thread. See [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) and [The Event Dispatch Thead](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html)
- No layout is set on `frame`, so it defaults to BorderLayout. You should add `bgpanel` and `bgpanel2` with `add(bgpanel, BorderLayout.CENTER)` and `add(bgpanel2, BorderLayout.NORTH)`. The `add(component)` defaults to `CENTER` so `bgpanel` replaces `bgpanel2` and the second panel is never rendered.
- In `actionPerformed` your're repeating the same sequence of operations for each button. This is generally and indication you should introduce a function to do the repetitive work.

All that said, what you have here is actually quite good for newbie code. Keep up the good work and welcome to Java!